# timeout, breaking pipes and wc

Tags: pipe, timeout

I had an idea to quickly benchmark some decompression programs. E.g. for gz, I would run the command:

```
timeout 10 zcat foo.gz | wc -c
```

Which would measure the amount of data the decompressor could extract in 10 seconds.

The only problem is, that it does not work: as zcat is killed, wc is also killed, so I do not get the byte count, just a `Terminated` message.

So, the question is: **is there a way to get the count from wc**, either by blocking the signal somehow, or use an alternative instead of wc that prints a result even when it gets a term signal.

---

Of course, there are alternatives:

1. Writing to a temporary file:
   `timeout 10 zcat foo.gz > /dev/shm/x ; du -sb /dev/shm/x ; rm -r /dev/shm/x`
   The problem with this is that is uses a lot of memory, and also may have some performance penalty.
2. Using ulimit instead:
   `ulimit -t 10; zcat foo.gz | wc -c`
   This also works, but measures only cpu time, so slowdown due to I/O (e.g. because the compression is worse, and more bytes need to be read from disk) is not measured.
3. Making smaller test files:
   Well, this can work of course, and may be the nicest solution. However, this creates a lot of temporary files.

Comment: As I read "breaking pipes and wc" I thought at first you were having problems with your plumbing!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can place the timeout command in a subshell and make it succeed:

```
( timeout 10 <command> || true ) | wc -c
```

Comment: Making a failed command succeed? Oh, this looks so evil :D

Comment: @Erathiel Wanna smile while being evil? Try this one (it's equivalent to the above): `(timeout 10 <command> || :) | wc -c`

Comment: I tried using a subshell, but did not think about making it succeed. Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Just after posting, I had a thought to use named pipes for the process:

```
mkfifo /tmp/x; wc -c /tmp/x & timeout 10 zcat foo.gz > /tmp/x &
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `timeout --foreground` option, to make timeout only consider the immediate process and not the whole process group associated with the pipeline